# Core Text glyph placement and em values

Tags: cocoa, core-text, glyph

I am trying to draw some musical notes using the Bravura font from http://blog.steinberg.net/2013/05/introducing-bravura-music-font/ using core text functions.

A metadata json file accompanying this font has an "attach" coordinate in em unit fractions  for where stems should be attached to certain musical notes. This attachment point is relative to a bounding box around the note glyph again with the dimensions in fractions of em unit.

My crude ASCII picture shows the attach point of the stem to the musical note:

```
      |
      |
      |
 /---\* <- attach point here
|     |
 \---/
```

From wikipedia:
"An em is a unit of width in the field of typography, equal to the currently specified point size. For example, one em in a 16-point typeface is 16 points wide. Therefore, this unit is the same for all typefaces at a given point size."

I would like to use the `Core Text` function `CTFontDrawGlyphs` which takes a coordinate in pixels to use for the glyph placement.

I would also like to use the Core Graphics functions `CGContextMoveToPoint`, `CGContextAddLineToPoint` to draw the stems that attach to the musical note glyphs.

I'm a bit unclear how to go from a coordinate in em unit fractions to a particular coordinate in pixels for a glyph of a particular point size so that I can accurately place these stems to the musical note glyph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of a text transformation matrix (`CGContextSetTextMatrix`), 1 em will the be the same number of points as the font size. So for a 12 point font with the default identity text matrix, 1 em = 12 pt.

Note that almost nothing in Core Graphics is given in pixels. They're in points (Core Graphics points, not PostScript points). For a retina display, 1 point contains 4 pixels (2x2). This is probably what you mean anyway, but if you interact with images, the point/pixel conversion is very important.

(I kind of feel like I've repeated what you already know; is there more to the question? From a given origin, you would compute the coordinate by multiplying the em unit offset by the font size.)

Comment: Thanks Rob. So would I be correct in thinking I use something like CGFontGetGlyphBBoxes to get the bounding box for a glyph. The values returned for the bounding box will be in points and I should be able to perform the calculation as you suggest.

Comment: Yes, that should be right. I believe CGFontGetGlyphBBoxes returns points. If you get bizarre answers (say hundreds of times what you expect), use GCFontGetUnitsPerEm to convert from glyph space units to ems. But generally CG functions that return glyph space units are documented to note that.